# Problem run android studio emulator in vscode

Tags: javascript, java, android, node.js, nodejs-server

I'm trying to run my emulator through vscode every time I give npx command react-native run-android I get this error info Starting JS server...
The system cannot find the path specified.
info Launching emulator...
error Failed to launch emulator. Reason: No emulators found as an output of `emulator -list-avds`.
warn Please launch an emulator manually or connect a device. Otherwise app may fail to launch.

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor

error Failed to install the app.

I updated node configured, path, json and nothing resolved, i am used windows 11 android studio giraffe my vitualization is atived.